# Python threading how get output of multiprocess in sequence

Tags: python-multithreading

I am using Python threading to process multiple files and I want output of each of the files 0 through 100 being processed to be written in a file in orderly fashion

Currently I am saving output of all the thread as they get executed and hence the order is not maintained.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you post any relevant code samples to illustrate the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you create a list of 101 elements, 0 through 100. Then store the output from processing file x into list element x. When all processing is complete, write the data in the list elements from 0 to 100 to the file.